# How to get the value of radio type with JS And Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have form and try to get the value of the input type = radio with JS
And my form look like this :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 margin-top-10">
   <label><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Choisir le modèle :</label>
   <div class="radio-list">
      <div id="ete_reservation_settings_mode_product">
         <input type="radio" id="ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_0" name="ete_reservation_settings[mode_product]" required="required" value="1">
         <label for="ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_0" class="required">Mono Produit</label><input type="radio" id="ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_1" name="ete_reservation_settings[mode_product]" required="required" value="2" checked="checked">
         <label for="ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_1" class="required">Multi Produit</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So far I've tried

```
$("input[name*=ete_reservation_settings_mode_product").change(function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

And

```
$("#ete_reservation_settings_mode_product").change(function() { 
    $("input[name=ete_reservation_settings[mode_product]").change(function() { 
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: $("input[name*=ete_reservation_settings_mode_product").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

Comment: $("#ete_reservation_settings_mode_product").change(function() {
        $("input[name=ete_reservation_settings[mode_product]").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code, don't write it in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$("input[name=ete_reservation_settings\\\[mode_product\\\]]").change(function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

or

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "on change" you're either trying to get either of:

1. The **selected input's value** i.e. value="1" or value="2"
2. The **selected input's id** i.e. "ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_0" or "ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_1"
3. The **selected input's label text** i.e. "Mono Produit" or "Multi Produit"

---

Using Jquery ($), and a change function, we can do this:

```
var containerSelector = '#ete_reservation_settings_mode_product';

$(containerSelector + ' input').change(function() {

  var valueOfSelectedInput = $(this).val();
  var selectedInput = $(containerSelector).find('input[value="' + valueOfSelectedInput + '"]');
  var selectedInputId = selectedInput.attr('id');
  var correspondingLabel = $(containerSelector + ' label[for="' + selectedInputId + '"]');
  var correspondingLabelText = correspondingLabel.text();

  // outputs: '1' or '2'
  console.log(valueOfSelectedInput);

  //outputs 'ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_0' or 'ete_reservation_settings_mode_product_1'
  console.log(selectedInputId);

  //outputs 'Mono Produit' or 'Multi Produit'
  console.log(correspondingLabelText);

});
```

Please not that I've used `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Open up your browser's console to see these. If you don't know where this is, simply search "How to find the console in X (e.g. chrome, safari, firefox, explorer) browser?"

See working fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/2f1qmfv4/